# On Chained static library, Do i have to add all libraries chained?

Tags: c++, linux, static-libraries

I made static library `A`, the library is using another static library `B`.

And in order to use library `A` in code `C`, i added library `A` and header `A` but `B`.

Because i have known that static library is combined in compile time, so library `B` is already contained within `A`.

But When i compile code `C`, it seem to require that i add library `B` also showing undefined reference error.

And when i add library B also, the error disappear.

Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add both A and B.

When static lib A uses static lib B, B is absolutely NOT combined in A. That is impossible since when generating static libraries there is no link step.

This is the difference between shared and static libraries on Linux.

If your library is written well, you may not need to add B headers in code C, but when linking, (executable or shared library or even DLL in windows) you'll need all used static libraries.